# Unable to use WebService specifing the URI through code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have two PCs conected with a LAN. Firewall ports are opened.
I'm running a WebService on A machine, using IIS. Of course, I can access the WebService (on A) through the Web Browser on the B machine, so I'm sure the WebService can be accessed remotely.

Now, I'm running a console app on B machine, developed in vb.net, which will access the WebService of A machine.

Both, the console app and the WebService, has been developed on VS2010.

Creating the reference on the project, I can see and use the WebService. But I need to specify on code the URI due to the WebService may change its location.

The code indicating the URI manually:

> Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.WebServiceSoapClient("192.168.1.13:8080")

This line throw an exception with the message that did not find any element with the name indicated. I have tried too, without success, the following lines:

This one:

> Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.WebServiceSoapClient("192.168.1.13")

And this one:

> Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.WebServiceSoapClient("192.168.1.13:8080/ServicioWeb.asmx")

But the result is always the same.

Some user (raja) wrote an answer a few days ago indicating that this should work, but I don't know the reason why does not work in my case.

As I said before, if I create the reference on the project, and I use the following line of code:

> Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.WebServiceSoapClient()

It works!, but what I need is to set the URI manually...

Some help will be thankful.

Comment: `ASMX` is a bit dated, the new standard is `WCF`.

Comment: I'll take a look to WCF.

Comment: Question updated with new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if not already present, you need to modify the proxy class to have a constructor that can take a Uri and set it. This Uri needs to be supplied to the proxy.

```
Dim uriFromConfig as String;

// read uriFromConfig from config or set it accordingly.    
Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.ServicioWebSoapClient(uriFromConfig);
```

this way, any ASMX can be called, as long as the right Uri is provided.

in summary to call a webservice hosted on machine with IP a.b.c.d from another machine:

1. Give the Proxy Uri with the IP Address. a.b.c.d
2. Open the port (50594) you're using in the machine hosting the web service from the Firewall settings.
3. Verify if the asmx is accesible by typing http://a.b.c.d:50594/ServicioWeb.asmx from the browser of the client machine. (not the machine hosting the web service)

if #3 is successful, then you'll see a nice page on the browser.
your client app should also be able to connect now.

Comment: Following your indications, and knowing that the WebService is located at "http://localhost:50594/ServicioWeb.asmx", I have tried this:                                                                   Dim myService As New MiServicioWeb.ServicioWebSoapClient("http://localhost:50594/ServicioWeb.asmx"), but without success.

Comment: Instead of local host you need to give the ip address of the machine hosting the web service. Also to access the URL remotely you need to open the port you're using in the firewall. You can verify by typing the asmx URL in the browser and seeing if the page comes up.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the troubles I'm still getting.

Comment: If you are accessing web service on machine A from machine B, then use ip address or machine name of machine A. 127.0.0.1 is not right as it still points to the local host.

Comment: You mean that the only way to make work by specifying the ip is that the WebService can not be hosted on the same machine that the console app?. At this point of the development, I'm working on the same machine, so both app (WebService and Console app) are running on the same machine.